# Invoke-WebRequest nested response formatting

Tags: json, powershell, webrequest

First time posting so apologies if I miss some etiquette here. I have begun playing around with WebRequests in Powershell to collate some useful parts of a JSON (see below) below with the eventual aim of linking it to a GUI.

I'm running the following

`$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/P81085'|convertFrom-Json |select -expand Organisation`

The full response is returned as a JSON as such:

```
{
    "Organisation": {
        "Name": "YORK BRIDGE SURGERY",
        "Date": [
            {
                "Type": "Operational",
                "Start": "1974-04-01",
                "End": "2018-05-02"
            },
            {
                "Type": "Legal",
                "Start": "1974-04-01",
                "End": "2018-04-30"
            }
        ],
        "OrgId": {
            "root": "2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48",
            "assigningAuthorityName": "HSCIC",
            "extension": "P81085"
        },
        "Status": "Inactive",
        "LastChangeDate": "2018-05-04",
        "orgRecordClass": "RC1",
        "GeoLoc": {
            "Location": {
                "AddrLn1": "5 JAMES STREET",
                "Town": "MORECAMBE",
                "County": "LANCASHIRE",
                "PostCode": "LA4 5TE",
                "Country": "ENGLAND"
            }
```

Which is displayed in PS as:

```
Date           : {@{Type=Operational; Start=1974-04-01; End=2018-05-02}, @{Type=Legal; Start=1974-04-01; End=2018-04-30}}
OrgId          : @{root=2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48; assigningAuthorityName=HSCIC; extension=P81085}
Status         : Inactive
LastChangeDate : 2018-05-04
orgRecordClass : RC1
GeoLoc         : @{Location=}
Contacts       : @{Contact=System.Object[]}
Roles          : @{Role=System.Object[]}
Rels           : @{Rel=System.Object[]}
```

I can assign variables and call individual sections by setting the below:

```
$name = $response.Name
$date = $response.date
```

Which return:

```
YORK BRIDGE SURGERY
Type        Start      End       
----        -----      ---       
Operational 1974-04-01 2018-05-02
Legal       1974-04-01 2018-04-30
```

However if I set:

```
$address = $response.geoloc
```

I get back the following

```
Location-------- @{AddrLn1=5 JAMES STREET; Town=MORECAMBE; County=LANCASHIRE; PostCode=LA4 5TE; Country=ENGLAND}
```

Is anyone able to suggest a way I would be able to return just individual sections of the location data?
Ideally I'd like to be able to set $town = $response.town and have it return just "Morecambe" in this example however I'm clearly missing something obvious

Comment: You just need to drill down further into the properties --> `$response.geoloc.location.town`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response.Organisation.geoloc.Location
$response.Organisation.geoloc.Location.County
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks, I had just come to post that I'd figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

For anyone who may have the same issue in the future:

```
$addrLn1 = $response.geoloc.location.addrLn1
$addrLn2 = $response.geoloc.location.addrLn2
$town = $response.geoloc.location.town
```

Allowed me to set the variables I needed, which returned the individual data I needed.

In retrospect, obvious but I'm still starting out, hopefully this'll help someone else one day